# Got error on passing method as parameter on another method inside class

Tags: javascript, typescript

```js
class Parser {
 private tokens: Array<ITokenized>
 private token_index: number;
 private current_token: ITokenized | undefined;

 constructor(tokens: Array<ITokenized>) {
  // console.log(tokens);
  this.tokens = tokens
  this.token_index = -1;
  this.current_token = undefined
  this.next()
 }

 next() {
  this.token_index += 1;
  if (this.token_index < this.tokens.length) {
   this.current_token = this.tokens[this.token_index]
  }
  return this.current_token
 }

 public parse(): any {
  let result = this.expression();
  return result;
 }

 private factor() {
  let token = this.current_token
  if ([TOK_INT, TOK_FLOAT].includes(token?.dataType)) {
   this.next();
   return new NumberNode(token?.value).represent();
  }
 }

 private term() {
  return this.binaryOperation(this.factor, [TOK_MULTI, TOK_DIVI])
 }

 private expression() {
  return this.binaryOperation(this.term, [TOK_PLUS, TOK_MINUS])
 }

 public binaryOperation(func: Function, operator: Array<string>) {
  let leftNode, operationToken, rightNode;
  leftNode = func()
  while (operator.includes(this.current_token?.dataType)) {
   operationToken = this.current_token;
   this.next();
   rightNode = func()
   leftNode = new BinaryOperator(leftNode, operationToken?.dataType, rightNode).represent();
  }

  return leftNode;
 }
}


export default Parser;
```

> F:\Programming-Files\hello-world\dev-projects\puCpp-programming-language\src\parser\Parser.ts:69
>                   return this.binaryOperation(this.factor, [TOK_MULTI, TOK_DIVI])
>                 ^ TypeError: Cannot read property 'binaryOperation' of undefined
>       at Parser.term (F:\Programming-Files\hello-world\dev-projects\puCpp-programming-language\src\parser\Parser.ts:69:15)
>       at Parser.binaryOperation (F:\Programming-Files\hello-world\dev-projects\puCpp-programming-language\src\parser\Parser.ts:78:14)
>       at Parser.expression (F:\Programming-Files\hello-world\dev-projects\puCpp-programming-language\src\parser\Parser.ts:73:15)
>       at Parser.parse (F:\Programming-Files\hello-world\dev-projects\puCpp-programming-language\src\parser\Parser.ts:56:21)
>       at Runner.start (F:\Programming-Files\hello-world\dev-projects\puCpp-programming-language\src\lexer\Runner.ts:21:26)
>       at F:\Programming-Files\hello-world\dev-projects\puCpp-programming-language\src\index.ts:25:46
>       at Interface._onLine (readline.js:306:5)
>       at Interface._line (readline.js:656:8)
>       at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:937:14)
>       at Socket.onkeypress (readline.js:184:10)

Comment: How are you calling `binaryOperation`?

Comment: I would say keyword "this" is the problem on this.binaryOperation, check if its relevant and not undefined. It depends on where you are calling the function from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try explicitly binding your function arguments:

```
private term() {
        return this.binaryOperation(this.factor.bind(this), [TOK_MULTI, TOK_DIVI])
    }

private expression() {
        return this.binaryOperation(this.term.bind(this), [TOK_PLUS, TOK_MINUS])
    }
```